# How can I display only 30 characters maximum in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to do something like this.

I have this text in a variable :

`let text = 'hey this is a super long phrase'`

And I want to use a label to display the text, but I want to display only a few characters.

For my variable text I wanna display only 5 characters.

`<label>{{text}}</label> //display the full text`

And I wanna do something like this :

`<label>{{text}}</label> //display only hey t`

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `text-overflow: ellipsis`?

Comment: Did you try something ? give us your code !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on which version of Vue you're using. Vue 2 supported [filters](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html) (or `pipes`):

```js
filters: {
  short: function (value) {
    return value.substr(0, 5); // just an example
  }
}
```

And then

```html
<label>{{ text | short }}</label>
```

---

In Vue 3 you just need to create a [computed property](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/computed.html#basic-example) (which was also possible in Vue 2, filters were just another way for that):

```js
computed: {
  shortText() {
    return this.text.substr(0, 5)
  }
}

// if you're using Composition API
const shortText= computed(() => text.value * 2); // if text is another ref
```

```html
<label>{{ shortText }}</label>
```

Comment: Yes it's more clean with a filter, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JavaScript expression](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Using-JavaScript-Expressions) in vuejs template.

```
<label>{{text.substring(0,5)}}</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

```js
document.body.innerHTML = 'hey this is a super long phrase'.slice(0, 5)
```